# Glossaries disabling a footnote on first use

Tags: footnotes, glossaries

I have set to for each glossary item (not acronym) a footnote on the first use. But now I have a glossary item which only appears in the table and I don't want to show a footnote for that single item. Is there any way to turn it of.

Comment: Please post some example code

Comment: Without an example I'd guess that you can define first={Compact disk (CD)} in the definition and use \glsfirst{label} in the text.

Comment: With no MWE or other comment from @dusha, it's hard to answer this. I've therefore closed - reopen if I've got this wrong.